# What port use stomp protocol?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stomp, sockjs

Spring Boot app is hosted on default port `server.port=8080` and when I connect to the server, JS client's code calls the same port `new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/api/streams');` but port use after connection established for WebSocket?

I suppose data exchange for websocket\stomp work on a different port. But wheat is number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there are acceptor elements configured to accept STOMP connections on ports 61616 and 61613.

https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html

Comment: How did you make the connection between the question and ActiveMQ Artemis? He doesn't mention it anywhere in his question and it's not tagged with `activemq-artemis`.

Answer (score 3):

WebSocket uses the HTTP connection, so it can use that port 8080, or a more normal port 443 (secure) or port 80 (insecure) connection.

A WebSocket connection is established by making an HTTP connection, then asking to upgrade the connection to a WebSocket connection.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) says it:

> WebSocket is distinct from HTTP. Both protocols are located at layer 7 in the OSI model and depend on TCP at layer 4. Although they are different, RFC 6455 states that WebSocket "is designed to work over **HTTP ports 443 and 80** as well as to support HTTP proxies and intermediaries," thus making it compatible with HTTP. To achieve compatibility, the WebSocket handshake uses the HTTP Upgrade header to change from the HTTP protocol to the WebSocket protocol.
>
> [image]